# ANOVA is significant but coefficients are not?

Tags: regression, anova, regression-coefficients

I was wondering how I would report this?

My ANOVA is significant but when I look at the model and the different predictors, there is no significance?

[image]

Comment: Why do you think the individual coefficients are not significant?  What threshold for significance are you using?

Comment: This isn't an uncommon situation. A set of predictors can collectively give statistically significant explanatory power but individually then can all be measured quite imprecisely.

Comment: I think @GeorgeSavva is alluding to a t-stat of 2.5 being not bad by historical criteria. On the other hand, there's a lot more skeptecism these days of t-stats in the 2 range in social science due to an increased appreciation of researcher degrees of freedom, specification search etc....: run enough regressions and it's not hard to get a t-stat of 2 that's actually spurious.